# maintaining selected tab between postback

Tags: jquery, tabs, postback

I am using jQuery tabs to display couple of of asp:listviews . every time a postback is done the tab is set to first tab. I am using the following code for to prevent this but not working

```
$(function () {
      $("#tabs").tabs({
          activate : function () {
              var selectedtab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
              $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
          },
          active : <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
      });
  });
```

Is there something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` tabs can use cookies to store the current tab. Please have a look at the tabs [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Tabs). You will find in the documentation to Get or set the cookie option, after init. The example code is:

```
//setter
$('.selector').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });

//getter
var cookie = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "cookie" );
```

**Dependency**

To use the cookie option you need to include [jQuery cookie plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

Enjoy...